# Why doesn't this digital root function work?

Tags: python

I'm doing [a challenge on codewars](http://www.codewars.com/kata/541c8630095125aba6000c00/train/python), and I'm supposed to write a digital root function in Python. I can't figure out why it's not working. This is my first attempt at recursion. I would really like to wrap my head around this.

```
def digital_root(num):
        #Check to see if num has more than one digit
        if num > 9:
            x = 0
            z = 1
            #Create an array of the digits in num
            digits = [int(d) for d in str(num)]

            #Convert string elements in digits[] to ints
            for n in digits:
                digits[x] = int(x)
                x = x + 1

            #Add each element in digits[] to digits[0]
            for n in digits:
                digits[0] = digits[0] + digits[z]

                #If digits[0] has more than one digit, then run digital_root with digits[0] in the parameters
                if digits[0] > 9:
                    digital_root(digits[0])
                else:
                    return digits[0]
        else:
            return num

digital_root(15)


>> Program finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Could you add a link to the actual Codewars problem?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce I just did :)

Comment: Don't you just want to `sum(digits)`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Not quite. The digital root of 99 is 9, not 18.

Comment: @user2357112 I should have elaborated. `sum(digits)` then recursively call.

Comment: The fact that the problem description uses the word "recursive" does not mean you need to use recursion in your solution. This is more easily solved without recursion.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You're probably right, I just didn't think about `sum(digits)`

Comment: @kindall Interesting! Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can use a simple `while` loop for this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with your function. Let's go down the list.

---

```
#Convert string elements in digits[] to ints
for n in digits:
    digits[x] = int(x)
    x = x + 1
```

This section is intended to convert the elements of `digits` into ints, but the elements of `digits` are *already* ints. The earlier list comprehension already produced ints:

```
digits = [int(d) for d in str(num)]
#         ^^^^^^
```

The whole section is unnecessary. It's not even filling `digits` with the right ints; instead of calling `int` on the elements of `digits`, it calls `int` on the indices. Also, the loop makes no use of the loop variable `n`.

---

```
for n in digits:
    digits[0] = digits[0] + digits[z]
```

This loop attempts to add all the digits together. However, `z` is never incremented, so this adds `digits[1]` to `digits[0]` every time. Also, even if the loop was changed to increment `z`, it would most likely go too far and run off the end of the list; `z` starts at 1, and the loop performs one iteration for each element of `digits`, so by the last iteration, `z` would be past the end of the list. Also, again, the `n` variable is unused.

Using `digits[0]` as a place to hold the sum muddles up the meaning of the `digits` array during the loop. It'd be better to use a separate variable (and doing so would avoid needing to start `z` at 1), but since Python already has a `sum` function, it'd be even simpler to just use `sum`.

---

```
#If digits[0] has more than one digit, then run digital_root with digits[0] in the parameters
if digits[0] > 9:
    digital_root(digits[0])
else:
    return digits[0]
```

This is inside the above loop, but it doesn't look like it's supposed to be; it looks like it was intended to run after `digits[0]` contains the sum. If so, it should be dedented (delete 4 spaces from each line). Also, since there's no `return` on the recursive call, the return value of the recursive call is discarded.

---

A corrected version of your function could look like

```
def digital_root(num):
    if num > 9:
        digits = [int(d) for d in str(num)]

        total = 0
        for n in digits:
            total += n

        if total > 9:
            return digital_root(total)
        else:
            return total
    else:
        return num
```

A simpler solution to the challenge, taking advantage of `sum`, would be

```
def digital_root(num):
    while num > 9:
        num = sum(map(int, str(num)))
    return num
```

or, keeping it recursive,

```
def digital_root(num):
    if num < 10:
        return num
    return digital_root(sum(map(int, str(num))))
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!